# if-image-height JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of several images on my website. Hovering on one of these images will display a label with a name and price. The problem is that some images have a smaller height, and then the label gets too close to the bottom. Now I'm trying to write a JS if-statement in order to decrease the margin-top of that label only **if** the image-height is less than 200px.

This is how my html looks like:

```
<div class="fw_preview_wrapper">
<img src="'.$row['imageURL'].'" alt="" class="fw_featured_image" id="product_image" width="540">
<span class="price_tag" id="price_tag"><span class="actual_price">€ '.$row['Price'].'</span>
```

As you can  see, the image URL is variable and comes from a database via php. For the js function, I set `id="product_image"`.

This is the CSS part:

```
span.price_tag {
top: 86%;
}
```

As you can see above, there is a margin top set to 86%. This very value needs to be changed to "80%" when an image has a height of less than 200px.

and finally, the JS part:

```
<script>
var img = document.getElementById('#product_image'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;

if(height < 200){
$("span.price_tag").css('top','80%');
}
</script>
```

It doesn't work. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hash `#` within param for getElementById:

```
var img = document.getElementById('product_image');
```

However you're using jQuery too, seeing your code, why not do just like this:

```
var img = $('#product_image'); 
var width = img.width();
var height = img.height();

if(height < 200){
$("span.price_tag").css('top','80%');
}
```

Comment: thanks! But there is still a problem. When I use this script, both images that are smaller than 200px and images that are bigger than 200px get affected (or not). I cannot seem to distinguish between the sizes, yet there are huge differences between the heights of the images... I'm thinking maybe the image variable doesn't get the image properly, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

in javascript you should be using:

```
var img = document.getElementById('product_image');
```

`#` is used in jquery like:  `var img = $("#product_image")`

Comment: thanks! But there is still a problem. When I use this script, both images that are smaller than 200px and images that are bigger than 200px get affected (or not). I cannot seem to distinguish between the sizes, yet there are huge differences between the heights of the images... I'm thinking maybe the image variable doesn't get the image properly, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

remove # from the element getting statement , we use # to specify id in Jquery and not in js
try this..

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var img = document.getElementById('product_image'); 
   var width = img.clientWidth;
   var height = img.clientHeight;

   if(height < 200)
        $("span.price_tag").css('top','80%'); 
 </script>
```